# How can one define a fractional-order derivative of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, fractional-calculus

I am not familiar much with fractional-order derivatives, for instance, if $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbf{R}^{n}$, then how can one define:
$$
D^{q-1}\mathbf{x}\quad\text{and}\quad D^{q}\mathbf{x}?\tag{1}
$$
I hope someone can suggest a more analytic expression for $(1)$

Comment: How would you define the ordinary derivative of a single point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (aside from considering it as a constant function)? Or do you mean the identity function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$?